Rope modelling with screw modifier
I'm modelling a rope using screw modifier (applied) on a circle (and unapplied curve modifier), so I've made a knot and tied it around a pole-like shape.
The issue is I have no idea how I could edit the geometry of the edge of the rope so it continues downwards into a flat surface like on the image below (i'm probably really bad at explaining visually but I hope you get it).
I need all the highlighted 3 edge circles
to end at the same level below.



I guess you should have done that before applying any modifiers...?

I don't see how not applying screw modifier could help me shape the edges like that. I have the curve modifier not applied yet, but it's probably not helpful

Well, I would extend the curve and shape it so that it does continue downwards. If the screw modifier would not have been applied, you could change the settings of it to make it work with the extended curve.

I actually have a backup file with no modifiers applied, but I still don't get how I could treat making that shape. My screw is made of 3 circles one on top of each other. What tools do I use to shape it?

Perhaps you should upload your file with unapplied modifiers to https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question. I would go about this task as follows: have the three circles, screw them, and then use a Curve modifier to shape the rope with some curve. Now if you want to extend the rope downwards or whatver direction, just extend the curve which it is following and change the parameters of the Screw modifier to make sure it fits. If you made your rope like this, it should be quite easy and obvious. If not, I wonder how did you make the rope?

I've updated my question with the blendfile. I don't know how extending curve could help me there as I don't need to make it longer, I need to reshape it to make it end at the same level. I have my initial screw made out of 3 circles one on another so I believe I'd have to edit it somehow, but I have no idea, especially that is just iterated 20 times to make the length. I believe I'd have to seperate it somewhere and do something, but it's complicated, so I'd like to know more about it (I'm a newbie at Blender)

For ropes I just apply the screw and close the holes manually, then use a boolean modifier to cut them at a certain place if I need to.

If you don't want to just apply the mod and use a bolean, what you can do instead is something like this:

Instead of using circles in the original, use single vertices. The screw will give you the 3 spiraling lines
Then you create another object with a geonodes set up that copies the geometry of the original object, turns the lines into Curves and the Curves into Meshes by giving them a round profile. You can close the caps by checking Fill Caps in the Curve to Mesh node.
Then you can deform this object however you want while still being able to modify the original crew modifier or the thickness of the strands by changing the radius of the Circle profile in the geonodes modifier
If you want the end to be flat you can also still use a boolean modifier on it


Thank you so much!! This looks promising, but I hadn't thought about boolean in the first place, because haven't used boolean before in any other modelling since worried about quad geometry. I might try it now.

@annie_pp If you want quad geometry then you'd have to apply all the modifiers and fix the geometry manually I think. I can't really think of a what to do that non destructively unless you want to add a remesh modifier to the rope as well.
If you do that, you only need to do it for 1 strand. Delete the other 2 and when you fix the remaining one just duplicate and rotate it 120º. Do this twice to get the 3 fixed strands

@Cornivius When all modifiers are applied, how will rotating by 120° work? It is not a straight line, if I understand the question correctly she has made a knot and tied it to a pole...

@GordonBrinkmann All modifier that make the core rope object I mean. It won't work once it's been deformed into place
